# Getting contact points on bodies in Cocos2d & Box2d

Tags: iphone, c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

> I'm very *new* to Cocos2d and Box2d, I
>   have been following [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and
>   generally hacking. However, I have one
>   problem I cannot solve.

I create 2 bodies and fixtures (in the Box2d world) and create a "Contact Listener" object. This object stores a list of contacts along with the "contact point".

When the two bodies collide a contact point is reported but this (I think) is in the world co-ordinate system.

My problem is I can't seem to convert the contact point to a usable co-ordinate on **both** of the bodies.

> I want to add a crack graphic to the
>   sprite (connected to the body) at the
>   point of contact on both
>   bodies/fixtures.

Has anyone solved this? I may be storing the "contact point" relative to the "world" is completely the wrong way to go.

Comment: Can you fix the link in ticked answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out [this](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.html#GetLocalPoint%28%29).  Take a look at `b2Body::GetLocalPoint(const b2Vec2 &worldPoint)`

Comment: Can you fix the link, it is missing.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to get the world-point (or points, max of 2 points are returned) where the collision took place. Within your `B2ContactListener` object, in `BeginContact` or `EndContact` functions:

```
b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold);
std::cout << "Contact point X: " << worldManifold.points[0].x * Ascengine::Physics::PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO << " Contact point Y: " << worldManifold.points[0].y  * Ascengine::Physics::PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO << std::endl;
```

From here, as Jason F mentioned, you can then use `b2Body::GetLocalPoint(const b2Vec2 &worldPoint)` to convert this world point to local object space. I just wanted to add my own answer to include the whole part about getting the world contact points, since this seems to be omitted altogether in the accepted answer.

Comment: Just as a note for people curious Ascengine::Physics::PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO is just a constant defined in my own game engine that gives me, well, as the name suggests, the pixel:meter ratio.